# react how to add images and call them in project

Tags: reactjs

Hey I am making a project with vite+react but I don't know how to use images

I  transfered an image to src/assets/images/logo.svg and called it as ./assets/images/logo.svg But its not showing in the webpage how do I get the images to show ?

Comment: Please add more specific details like sharing the related part of your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax to display images:

```
import example from '../assets/pos.png';

<div className="profile">
   <img src={example} height="300px" width="300px" />
</div>
```